# How to read redux state inside a component the right way?

Tags: reactjs, redux, components

I am having trouble understanding how to connect a component with my redux state(in the right way)

so far I tried using mapStateToProps, but have absolutely no idea where the data is stored afterwards, I even managed to get an instance inside the constructor, but it also feels wrong, in other components (which built in a strange way) I see programmers just pulling the the state out of thin air, but in my component(which is a class that extends 'component') I can only get the desired result by changing manually each change inside mapStateToProps.

the component where I try to get the state **(check the comment inside mapStateToProps, that's what I kinda want)**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import {initCreate} from "../../actions" 

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        initCreate: () => dispatch(initCreate())
    };
};
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    //this.state.toggleCreate = state.reduction.toggleCreate;  <= seems to work, but feels wrong? is this how it's done in react? 
    return state.reduction;
};
class CrudBar extends Component {
    constructor(reduction) {
        super();
        this.state = { toggleCreate: false};
        this.create = this.create.bind(this);
    }
    create() {
        this.props.initCreate();
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('state in component', this.state); // prints the state unchanged
        }, 1000);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.create}>Create</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
const toolBar = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CrudBar);
export default toolBar;
```

actions.js

```
export const addCategory = category => ({ type: "ADD_CATEGORY", payload: category });
export const initCreate = state => ({ type: "CRUDBAR_CREATE", payload: state });
```

my reducer:

```
const initialState = {
    toggleCreate: false,
};
const reductionReducer = (state = initialState, action) =>{
    switch (action.type) {
        case "CRUDBAR_CREATE":
        console.log('here') // printed
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('redux state', state); // prints the state changed
        }, 1000);
            return {
                toggleCreate: !state.toggleCreate,
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
export default reductionReducer;
```

the code where the programmer pulls the state out of thin air:

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return state.categories;
};

const CategoriesList = ({ categories }) => ( // I want something like this, to get the information and render accordingly
    <ul>
        {
             categories.map(el => (
            <li key={el.id}>
            {/* Name, Address, Coordinates, and Category. */}
               Name - {el.name}
            </li>
        )) }
    </ul>
);
const List = connect(mapStateToProps)(CategoriesList);
export default List;
```

I want the component to read the state out of redux,
and I want to do it, in the right way, not some cheap trick that other programmers would have to dance around and cringe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use redux state you need to get it from the store and inject it to the components props.

The way you do it is by first creating a function which returns the pieces of redux state you need in the particular component like this

```
const mapStateToProps = ({pieceOfReduxState, anotherPieceOfReduxStete}) =>
    ({pieceOfReduxState, anotherPieceOfReduxStete})
```

This return 2 pieces of redux state

Then you inject it as the first argument to the connect function

```
connect(mapStateToProps)(ComponentName)
```

This will make the redux store available in your components props

Then just use it in your component by accessing `this.props.pieceOfReduxState`

Hope this helps.